# How can I transfer MMS messages from an HTC One to a Galaxy S6?

Tags: restore, mms

I am trying to figure out how I can transfer all of my messages (SMS+MMS) from my old phone to my new phone. From what I can tell, most of the apps (SMS Restore+ and others) do not support MMS restore. I have Helium, and when I restore the "messaging storage", the MMS messages are not there. What else can I do? I really don't want to lose all of those messages!

Comment: You could try the [SMS Text Messaging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mightytext.tablet) app to migrate the messages over. It description claims the app is capable of that. Have not tried it, though (I not even have any MMS to try it with ;)